# Salesforce app license conversion

Tags: appexchange

We have a Salesforce application which is being listed at **Appexchange**, and we are providing trial of 45 days, many of the clients are using the application and for some trial period has been finished but they want to continue, so they can become the active user of our app.
For developer perspective, we are managing **LMO** at our organization and we can see the license has been expired for their org. Many documentation of Salesforce says that, we can change the License type from trial to active, but was not able to do even when we logged through License Manager credentials.

**So In short I want help at two points.**

- If we want to extend license for particular org, How can we do that
  from LMO?
- How can a customer himself expect to convert his license    from
  trial to active, without loosing the application data?

Answer (score 4):

I believe You Should  Use the License Management App (LMA) to apply licensing to your managed package to control how many users in the
installer's organization can access your package and for how long. Every time your package is installed, a lead record is created
in the LMA.

For more details Refer to the following link

- http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/lma/salesforce_lma_guide.pdf

Regards
Anchal Garg